# c# - крон на каждый день в 2 часа ночи

Tags: c#, cron

Как будет крон в ровно 2 часа ночи ежедневно на языке C# ?

Comment: Что значит "крон на языке C#"? cron это линуксовая служба, а C# это язык программирования

Comment: типа так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520478/cron-scheduler-every-day-at-12-midnight

Comment: @ShamilQurbanli `.WithCronSchedule("0 2 * * *")`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor там знак вопроса есть тоже, а это куда поставить надо ? не понимаю что это

Comment: Скорее `0 0 2 * * ?`

Comment: Вообще зачем вам это, в Windows есть хороший встроенный планировщик с очень гибкими настройками